# Remove duplicates using linq

Tags: linq

I know this as asked many times but cannot see something that works.
I am reading a csv file and then I have to remove duplicate lines based on one of the columns "CustomerID".
Basically the CSV file can have multiple lines with the same customerID.

I need to remove the duplicates.

```
    //DOES NOT WORK
     var finalCustomerList = csvCustomerList.Distinct().ToList();  

     I have also tried this extension method //DOES NOT WORK
     public static IEnumerable<t> RemoveDuplicates<t>(this IEnumerable<t> items)
        {
        return new HashSet<t>(items);
        }
```

What works for me is

- I Read the CSV file into a  csvCustomerList
- Loop through csvCustomerList and check if a
  customerExists   If it doesnt I add
  it.

  ```
   foreach (var csvCustomer in csvCustomerList)
   {
      var Customer = new customer();
      customer.CustomerID = csvCustomer.CustomerID;
      customer.Name = csvCustomer.Name; 
      //etc.....

      var exists = finalCustomerList.Exists(x => x.CustomerID == csvCustomer.CustomerID);
      if (!exists)
      {
         finalCustomerList.Add(customer);
      }
   }
  ```

  Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `Distinct` to work with non standard equality checks, you need to make your class `customer` implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx). In the `Equals` method, simply compare the customer ids and nothing else.
As an alternative, you can use [the overload of Distinct that requires an `IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) and create a class that implements that interface for `customer`. Like that, you don't need to change the `customer` class.
Or you can use Morelinq as suggested by another answer.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.However Cannot modify the class

Answer (score 3):

For a simple solution, check out [Morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) by Jon Skeet and others.

It has a `DistinctBy` operator where you can perform a distinct operation by any field. So you could do something like:

```
var finalCustomerList = csvCustomerList.DistinctBy(c => c.customerID).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks that would work just fine.Not sure I am allowed to ref another third party library

Comment: @user231465 - then look at the source and pretend you wrote it yourself. http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs ;-) (only joking of course...)